# Android Tab Layout with View Pager

Tags: android

i am using tab layout with view pager which contains 4 tabs and my question is,how to set onLongClickListener on the tab and then rename it?
Thanks in Advance.!

Answer (score 0):

**for onLongClickListener**

```
View tabView= mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i);
// set the tag information at the view of the tab (the tag contains the position number of the tab)
tabView.setTag( Integer.valueOf(i));
tabView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // I print the number position of the tab
                Log.d("tab number", ((Integer)view.getTag()).toString() );
                return false;
            }
        });
```

**for Rename tab**

```
((TextView)((RelativeLayout)getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabIndex)).getChildAt(textIndex)).setText("NewTabText");
```

Comment: please have a try. I hope it will work or share your code so that I can try to fix that properly.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
try like this.

 private void changeTabsText() {

    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
    int tabsCount = vg.getChildCount();
    for (int j = 0; j < tabsCount; j++) {
        ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(j);
        int tabChildsCount = vgTab.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < tabChildsCount; i++) {
            View tabViewChild = vgTab.getChildAt(i);
            if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView) tabViewChild).setText("your Text");
            }
        }
    }
}
```